# Iterate through array of classes Angular4

Tags: javascript, css, angular, swiper.js

I'm currently using the Swiper (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper) to create a gallery of images.

Is it possible to dynamically change the class of a div by iterating through an Array of objects and using ngClass? I'm not sure if it is supported with interpolation.

The error that I keep getting says "Identifier 'style' is not defined. 'Array' does not contain such a member.' But why is it that ngStyle, the h4 and p are able to grab the elements and iterate through it if that's the case?

slider.component.html

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <swiper class="swiper" [config]="config">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" *ngFor="let image of images">
            <div class="swiper-slide--container">
              <div class="symptom-slide-img"
              [ngClass]="images.style" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image.src + ')'}"></div>
              <div class="caption">
                  <h4>{{ image.title }}</h4>
                  <p>{{ image.caption}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </swiper>
</div>
```

slider.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgClass } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-symptoms-slider',
  templateUrl: './symptoms-slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./symptoms-slider.component.scss']
})
export class SymptomsSliderComponent implements OnInit {

images = [  {
                'src': './path/image.png',
                'title': 'Title',
                'style': 'hvr-pulse-grow',
                'caption':
                'Caption'
            },
            {
                'src': './path/image.png',
                'title': 'Title',
                'style': 'hvr-buzz',
                'caption':
                'Caption'
            },
            {
                'src': './path/image.png',
                'title': 'Title',
                'style': 'hvr-wobble-vertical',
                'caption':
                'Caption'
            },
            {
                'src': './path/image.png',
                'title': 'Title',
                'style': 'hvr-wobble-vertical',
                'caption':
                'Caption'
            },
        ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typo

`[ngClass]="images.` to `[ngClass]="image.` (remove unnecessary 's')

Comment: Clearly I've been working too long on this and needed a break. Thank you!